# Gradle projects vs. Eclipse projects?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I found an interesting open-source layout library on Github which I'd like to incorporate into an Android project I'm working on in Eclipse. However, I noticed that the library in question seems to have been developed using Gradle, which I don't have. I'm not sure what IDE was used to develop the library, but in any case, I'm not familiar with Gradle at all... Are Gradle-d projects fully compatible with non-Gradle-d Eclipse? Would it depend on the IDE used? (In which case, how can one tell what was used to develop it?)

What are the steps (if any) I would need to take to properly incorporate this library? Would I need to install & run certain plugins, for example?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am so very sorry for the "broad"-ness of this question. D: Indeed, I cannot be sure that I know of a good way to reword it so as to "narrow the answer set"... as it was, I was looking for a short, general answer to this issue, for which I was not able to find a concise shorthand summary online. After all, formal technical explanations CAN be so trying for newbies. I do believe that I have found what I've been looking for in the answer given here and do very much thank the StackOverflow community for both their expertise and their patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle is the build system that Android Studio uses (the new IDE that is being developed by Google for Android development). You can use the [`Gradle Eclipse plugin`](http://www.gradle.org/tooling) to load Gradle projects into Eclipse.

Comment: I want to add that Gradle is the new Android build system and is not tied to an IDE. You can write android code where ever you want and use gradle to build your project.